# Gmail "Отправлено через"

Tags: dns, email, gmail

Проблема возникла после переезда на другой хостинг (на IHC). Прописаны ns-сервера cloudflare, при отправке писем с сервера, Gmail пишет `info@domain.com через xxx.ihc.ru`

В функции mail() указан 5й параметр `$mail = mail($mreceiver, $msubject, $message, $headers, '-f'.$settings[infoemail].'');`

Как уйти от этого "Отправлено через" ?

Comment: Google определяет это по ключу dkim. Домен в поле "От" должен совпадать с доменом который используется для аутентификации писем.

Comment: Да вроде совпадает, на предыдущем хостинге всё было в порядке. После переезда никаких изменений в коде не было